# Is it possible to check whether the serial port is free or occupied?

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I am using boost asio library for Serial Port Communication.

I run this for "COM3" port on windows. It runs well when the port "COM3" is free, but when other application has already occupied "COM3" port, this code throws exception.

And after exception, the application will terminate.

I want to continue with the application. So, my requirement is : can I check whether port "COM3" is free to use or occupied by some application?

Code is ::

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::serial_port* port;

try{
    port = new boost::asio::serial_port(io_service, "COM3");
}
catch(boost::system::system_error& e)
{
    cout<<"Error: " << e.what()<<endl;
    cout<<"Info: "  << boost::diagnostic_information(e) <<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Missing something here, you have a try catch, are you not catching the correct exception????

Answer (score 2):

"can I check whether port "COM3" is free to use" - Yes: If calling

```
port = new boost::asio::serial_port(io_service, "COM3");
```

does not throw an exception you are ready to use the port:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::serial_port* port;

try{
    port = new boost::asio::serial_port(io_service, "COM3");
    // Port is now ready to be used by your application.
}
catch(boost::system::system_error& e)
{
    // Opening the port did not work, go on with error-handling
    cout<<"Error: " << e.what()<<endl;
    cout<<"Info: "  << boost::diagnostic_information(e) <<endl;
    // If you call return 1 from your main-function, the app will exit:
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: But after it throws an exception, the application will exit. right? I want to continue with the application

Comment: @skc so, don't exit? Perhaps you shouldn't `return 1`?

Comment: @skc: No, an application will not always exit if an Exception is thrown: If you catch the exception, the exception is "handled" by your application, and the application will do whatever you tell it to do in the catch-block. If you do not catch the Exception, the programm will probably exit with something like "Fatal Exception". See here for more information about exception-handling: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Exception_Handling

Comment: Oops..
My mistake..

I should have looked at the Exceptions first before posting a question..

Answer (score -2):

Found solution to my problem here: https://gist.github.com/yoggy/3323808

If I use boost::shared_ptr instead, it will not throw an exception but will give some error code, and I will be able to continue with my application.

Comment: This, frankly, is a load of crap. The overload taking `boost::system::errorcode&` doesn't throw, but it has ***nothing*** at all to do with shared pointers

Comment: Agree..

In fact, I misunderstood( honestly, forgot) the Exceptions..

My mistake..

shared_ptr is not required, if I handle the exception.